# Customer Ratings on Apple Appstore?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, ios-appstore, data-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ratings and Reviews not showing up for newly released app. Is there a standard delay or is something wrong?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/ratings-and-reviews-not-showing-up-for-newly-released-app-is-there-a-standard-de)

I don't know whats wrong with Apple Customer Ratings system on Appstore.

Recently I have uploaded two apps on appstore. And still there are no ratings/reviews on apps. Infact I observed there are 1000s of downloads has been made in last 2 days.

To verify this 1 of my friend also added his comment with rating yesterday on 1 of my App. But his comment also not visible, still there are zero customer reviews in both Apps.

Can anyone update me regarding this issue ?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6405/5472 - it's likely that a number of reviews are needed to kick an app into the status where reviews become published. Have you tried asking developers on the apple developer forums - they might be more likely to answer there.

Comment: bmike is right; this is a duplicate. Also, in the future, please keep the rant out of your question. The words "I don't know what's wrong with..." are unnecessary. Thanks for your cooperation.