# How do I view negative reviews for a podcast in the iTunes store?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, app-store-connect

How do I read negative reviews for a podcast in the iTunes store? It looks like they are censoring reviews. I myself wrote a negative review but I don't see it showing up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not all reviews get posted and sometimes the delay is days or weeks for some reviews to show. I believe the stars get updates much more rapidly as a human doesn't need to review those ratings like Apple does for the word portions of reviews.

This is similar to app reviews:

- [Is there a standard delay for consumer ratings of apps on the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/)
- [Why do iPhone App Store ratings and reviews seem to get processed so slowly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8508/)

I believe if you put star ratings in and feel they aren't updating, a request to the iTunes store support team might help unstick a podcast with problems updating. https://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/ and choose Store Support.